# Angular Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, angular-errorhandler

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
**Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
**Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

source Code:

"use strict";
/**

- @license
- Copyright Google LLC All Rights Reserved.
- 
- Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
- found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
  */
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  exports.AngularWebpackLoaderPath = exports.AngularWebpackPlugin = exports.default = void 0;
  var loader_1 = require("./loader");
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "default", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return loader_1.angularWebpackLoader; } });
  var plugin_1 = require("./plugin");
  Object.defineProperty(exports, "AngularWebpackPlugin", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return plugin_1.AngularWebpackPlugin; } });
  exports.AngularWebpackLoaderPath = __filename;

I faced this type of error. How can I resolve it? Can anyone help me?

Comment: you are getting into infinite loop. more information needed to know why this is happening.

Comment: Pls post related code, infinite loop could be caused by a function calling itself